# how to fix ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead?

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X=data['reck']
y=data['price']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=0)

linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
```

I wrote codes for linear regression problem but this error appeared when i want to see result this error is:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
    array=[122360. 122365. 49800. ... 2696. 2357. nan].
Reshape your data either using
    array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or
    array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

My model is just 1D. It tries to find relation between reception kilometer of cars and the price of services they have received.

```
chasis number reck price
 0 999.JACJ5AT.SPC00 122360.0 330000
 1 999.JACJ5AT.SPC00 122365.0 385000
 2 999.JACS5AT.SPC00 49800.0 753500
 3 999.JACS5AT.SPC00 49805.0 1732500
 4 999.JACS5AT.SPC00 49908.0 1375000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you are declaring the X and Y

if you print shape of X or Y

```
X.shape
```

it would come something like this

```
(49,)
```

Which says 49 rows , but column is blank

to avoid this , you can edit your code like this

```
X=data[['reck']]
y=data[['price']]
```

when you print the shape

```
X.shape
```

the value would come something like this

```
(49,1)
```

When you pass these values to your model, model will not throw any error.

PS : i am also a new contributor, i tried to explain it as much i understand, however there could be more logical explanation to this

Answer (score 0):

What about `reshape`ing array to 2D? (Note that the error message is verbose enough to propose it as well!)

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X=data['reck'].reshape(-1, 1)
y=data['price']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=0)

linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
```

Comment: thank you Tomasz. but when i reshape as you mentioned, i have this error:                                        
 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'